# is there a way to test onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) in android?

Tags: android, testing, oncreateoptionsmenu

i want to write a test to validate what i do in onCreateOptionsMenu
Can anyone assist me how to go about it?

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        setdate(menu,this);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

Comment: what's the exact problem/error you got ?

Comment: i just cant figure a way to write a test for it?that is how to validate that the right menu is shown and setdate is called

Answer (score -1):

For testing, if you want to check whether setDate() is called, you can add logs and check them in DDMS -> Logcat :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        Log.d("tag","onCreateOptionsMenu calling setDate");
        setdate(menu,this);
        Log.d("tag","onCreateOptionsMenu called setDate");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

On Display, the menu stored at **R.menu.global** will be displayed

Answer (score -1):

set this changes in res/menu/main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/testMenu"
    android:title="@string/test"/>
</menu>
```

and in your Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.testMenu:
        //here write your action or call your method for example: setData()
        Log.i("TEST_MENU" , "Test Passed");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```